# Permanent in-mission saves in Hitman blood money?

Tags: hitman-blood-money

In Hitman 4, it's not possible to have permanent in-mission saves. I mean by "permanent", those you can have even after you exit the game and launch it later.

I've tried to minimize the game, **copy** the saves in **my documents**, exit the game, relaunch the game, paste what I copied in my documents. But this didn't work.

***Is there any way where I can keep my in-mission saves?***